# Can I use placement new for object graphs of third party classes?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I'm using a tool called Emscripten, which compiles LLVM IR to Javascript. Emscripten models the C++ heap as just one huge Javascript array. If you create a web worker with Emscripten, you end up with a brand new 'instance' of Emscripten, and hence a new 'heap' represented by a separate Javascript array.

As Javascript doesn't have threads or shared memory, the only way I can split up work is with web workers. However, I don't want to have to serialise results (as it's really slow for the particular objects I'm using), so need to find a way to allocate my intermediate results to a byte array (before then in Javascript world passing a message back with a copy of this array)

From the top level object that's fine, but internally it's just using a regular 'new' operator, which could again be anywhere in the heap.

The other tricky thing is reading out these objects from the allocated byte array when I access it from a new 'heap' - the internal pointers would be all messed up.

I've seen how it's possible to write 'bump' or 'offset' allocaters, but I don't see how to get these to work transparently with an existing class structure that you don't want to change or can't change.

Comment: You cannot copy even individual C++ objects as byte arrays. You can use placement new in an existing byte array, but once you do that, the object address is set in concrete. You cannot move or copy the underlying memory.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm getting at. If you can use placement new, you *can* copy the buffer they were allocated to, to a completely new memory space, so long as the buffer is copied to the same offset. The only thing I'm missing is for internally created objects to use the same allocator

Comment: "you can copy the buffer". Sure, `memcpy` will succeed. The objects at the new location will be unusable though.

Comment: That's the whole point of the question. The copy wouldn't be unusable if it were copied to the *same* start location in a separate memory space. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. No you cannot magically make third party code use your placement new. You can however replace the global new operator. This is ugly and error-prone but there is no other chance.